# Two nights in Baltimore (MD): what parts of town to visit for dinner/drinks?

Tags: restaurants, nightlife, maryland, baltimore

I am staying in Baltimore, Maryland for two days for business during the day. 
Any good tips what where I should go in the city for food and drinks in the evening (for a non US-citizen)?

Comment: Hi Pieter, welcome to Travel.SE.  As it stands this question is too vague to fit into our site - see the [faq].  We try to write questions that can be answered objectively. There are literally hundreds of things that you could do in any city - what things are you interested in? Do you want to go to museums? Hit the town? Visit the stamp society?  If you could edit your question and be more precise about what you're after, we'll be happy to help answer.  :)

Comment: I edited the question to be more focussed on food and drinks.

Answer (score 3):

Baltimore is a beautiful city, with a lot of old world charm, clubbed with modern infrastructure. Especially with regards to food, it is often overlooked because of its close proximity to the nation's capital. I have visited Baltimore a few times, and have never been disappointed with the level of service and quality of food. You should try out the Blue Crabs, which are a Maryland specialty. If you are averse to peeling crabs, try the crabcakes. 
Two areas come to mind. The [Fells Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fell%27s_Point,_Baltimore) neighborhood and Baltimore's [Inner Harbor](http://baltimore.org/about-baltimore/inner-harbor). Both of these offer enough options to suit any palate - be it fine dining, or bar grub.
If you have time in the day, don't forget to check out the [Baltimore Aquarium](http://www.aqua.org/visit/baltimore).

Answer (score 3):

I was over in Baltimore last week, and handily had a friendly native to guide me around to the best spots :)

Fells Point had lots of very nice bars and restaurants, covering a wide range of tastes, so I'd say that's a must. A little bit east of that is O'Donnell Street, which had a similar selection of places but was a little quieter.

The Inner Harbour does have quite a few places to eat, but they tend to be either very pricey, or not all that great quality. I'd suggest you go there to look around (there's lots of museums, and walk up Federal Hill for some great views!), but maybe not to eat. If you go just away from the inner harbour (either inland or east) there are some good spots.

Finally, another good spot is just south of Federal Hill, around East Cross Street and William Street. Slightly different feel to Fells Point, but there was a good choice of nice places to drink and eat here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what these nice folks recommended, I'd add Camden Yard. Check out the [Orioles schedule](http://baltimore.orioles.mlb.com/schedule/index.jsp?c_id=bal#y=2012&m=5&calendar=DEFAULT). Take in a game if you get a chance. You can get a beer and a hotdog!